# java.io and socket.getInputStream()

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

I have this code:

```
 Socket incomingConnection = serverSocket.accept();
 String strategy = "1";
 Client client = new Client(incomingConnection, this, strategy);
```

**Constructor of Client**:

```
  public Client(Socket socket, ChatServer chatServer, String strategy) throws IOException{
        this.socket = socket;
        this.inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        this.outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        this.chatServer = chatServer;
        this.instance1 = new Strategy1(chatServer, this);
        this.instance2 = new Strategy2(chatServer, this);
        this.strategy = (this.instance1.getName().equals(strategy1) ? this.instance1 : this.instance2);
        this.strategy.setStreams();
    }
```

Now how looks like **Strategy1**:

```
public class Strategy1{
public Strategy1(ChatServer server, Client client) throws IOException{
    this.chatServer = server;
    this.client = client;
}

public void setStreams() throws IOException{
    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
}
```

And the same **Strategy2**.
**Method in Client class** :

```
client.getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}
// similar for outputStream
```

The problem is : when `Client`'s constructor tries to execute `strategy.setStreams()`, the program blocks on `new ObjectInputStream()`.

When I move `setStream()` method's containment into Constructor of `Strategy1` then it works!

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap these lines:

```
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
```

Creating an `ObjectInputStream` reads from the socket. If you create input streams first on both ends of the connection, it will deadlock. The safest is to always create output streams first.